# WCF fails to pass Uri

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, uri

I have a WCF named pipe service trying to pass a complex object,and failing each time - meaning the named pipe gets an excpetion on the client side:

> The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.

I tracked down the problem's cause to a bad Uri.

The Uri string is something like:

```
"http://www.example.com/,"
```

Now I realize this is a bad `Uri`, but it was created on the server non the less, and it even passes the `Uri.IsWellFormedUriString("http://www.example.com/,", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)` test.

I would prefer to find a way to allow it to pass through WCF without breaking the channel , or else finding a better uri test to allow me to disqualify such poorly behaved uris.

Comment: It passes for UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute

Comment: You were missing the protocol. Indeed it works.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the whole Uri thing was a red herring, the WCF failed because on inherited type not declared with KnownTypeAttribute. The exception itself was not helpful at all in this case.